# BertForSequenceClassification Target size (torch.Size([1, 16])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([16, 7]))

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to train BERT model. My dataset has 7 classes(labels). I tried to fix it by adding unsqueeze(0). But it's not working either.

I also tried to change unsqueeze(0) to unsqueeze(7). It creates another error.

*Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 7)*
Kindy help me to fix this.

This is the model

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
                                                      num_labels = 7,
                                                      output_attentions = False,
                                                      output_hidden_states = False)
```

Here is the code

```
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):

    #set model in train mode
    model.train()

    #tracking variable
    loss_train_total = 0
    
    #set up progress bar
    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, 
                        desc='Epoch {:1d}'.format(epoch), 
                        leave=False, 
                        disable=False)
    
    for batch in progress_bar:
        #set gradient to 0
        model.zero_grad()

        #load into GPU
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)

        #define inputs
        inputs = {'input_ids': batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels': batch[2].unsqueeze(0)}
        
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        loss = outputs[0] #output.loss
        loss_train_total +=loss.item()

        #backward pass to get gradients
        loss.backward()
        
        #clip the norm of the gradients to 1.0 to prevent exploding gradients
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
        
        #update optimizer
        optimizer.step()

        #update scheduler
        scheduler.step()
        
        progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()/len(batch))})
```

This is the error

```
 0%|          | 0/4 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Epoch 1:   0%|          | 0/69 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  0%|          | 0/4 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-7e237f477d50> in <module>()
     25                   'labels': batch[2].unsqueeze(0)}
     26 
---> 27         outputs = model(**inputs)
     28         loss = outputs[0] #output.loss
     29         loss_train_total +=loss.item()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   2978 
   2979     if not (target.size() == input.size()):
-> 2980         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   2981 
   2982     return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([1, 16])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([16, 7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not understand how this model is working internally.

1. The error shows that they are using `binary_cross_entropy_with_logits` as loss function (and not `binary_cross_entropy`). So, if the number of classes is 7, the ground truth (here called `label`) should be a vector of 7 values (ideally an one hot encoded form of the correct label). Say for data point d[i], correct label is 1, then the label corresponding to that datapoint should be a vector of length 7 (`[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`).
2. You are using a batch size of 16, so for evaluating the loss, the `label` shape should be `(16, 7)` as the error mentions.

#### Fixing issues:

1. changing `'labels': batch[2].unsqueeze(0)` to `'labels': batch[2]` would change labels shape from `(1, 16)` to `16`.
2. To go from shape `16` to `(16, 7)`, you will have to update your `dataloader_train` in such a way that, `batch[2]` has the appropriate shape (currently it contains a single value, it should be a tensor of length 7, containing one hot representation of the actual ground truth label).

### update

Here is a quick Hacky fix, that you could use in case you are not sure about updating the dataset:

```
import torch
batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)

labels = batch[2]
labels = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(labels, 7).squeeze(1) 
# labels should now be a tensor of shape (batch_size, 7)
# in your case, batch_size is 16.
# confirm by print(labels.shape). you can also try to print the
# tensor print(labels)

inputs = {'input_ids': batch[0],
          'attention_mask': batch[1],
          'labels': labels}
```

Now instead of doing `'labels': batch[2].unsqueeze(0)}`, use `'labels':labels`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This is the dataloader_train code. Can you help me to update it to have tensor of length 7

`from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler

batch_size = 16

#train set
dataloader_train = DataLoader(dataset_train,
                              sampler = RandomSampler(dataset_train),
                              batch_size = batch_size)

#validation set
dataloader_val = DataLoader(dataset_val,
                              sampler = RandomSampler(dataset_val),
                              batch_size = batch_size) `

Comment: Its difficult to fix it this way. I am not sure about your `dataset_train`. Try the hacky fix that I mentioned. Note that the fix is not a general solution.

Comment: Thanks. It fixed the error but generated new error ->>> **one_hot is only applicable to index tensor.** I fixed it with this code `labels = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(labels.to(torch.int64), 7).squeeze(1) ` .  Now there is new error --->>> **Expected input batch_size (16) to match target batch_size (112)**  This is the responsible line >>> `outputs = model(**inputs)`